# ArrayList manipulation in java

Tags: java, arraylist

```
Arraylist<Books> booksdtoList=new ArrayList<>();

List<Object[]> modelList =null;
modellist=repostory.getbooks("FICTION");
booksdtoList =mapdto(booksdtoList,modellist);
modellist=repostory.getbooks("COMIC");
booksdtoList =mapdto(booksdtoList,modellist);
```

```
Arraylist<Books> booksdtoList mapDto(Arraylist<Books> booksdtoList, List<Object[]> modelList){
    Books books=null;
    for (model:modelList){
        books=new Books((String)model[0],(String)model[1]));
        booksdtoList.add(books);
      
    }
    return booksdtoList;
}
```

Will `booksdtoList` contain all the list of books or will it override any object within list?

Is it best practice to send ArrayList as argument and add? If not please suggest best one.

Comment: `add(item)` on an `ArrayList` **always** means "add `item` to the list", **never** "[maybe] replace some existing item in the list with `item`", if that's what you're asking...

Answer (score 0):

I can't say really what is best practice but I would probably instantiate the List in the mapping method if it is always expected to be empty before calling it:

```
List<Books> mapDTO(List<Object[]> modelList) {
    List<Books> booksDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
    Books books = null;
    for (Object[] model : modelList){
        books = new Books((String)model[0], (String)model[1]);
        booksDTOList.add(books);

    }
    return booksDTOList;
}
```

Note also that it's best to use the List interface for the object.

To collect all books from multiple calls:

```
List<Books> booksDTOList=new ArrayList<>();
// ....
booksDTOList.addall(mapDTO(modelList1));
booksDTOList.addall(mapDTO(modelList2));
booksDTOList.addall(mapDTO(modelList3));
```

If you *do* choose to pass the list to the mapping method, you don't need to return it since Java is pass by reference (the list object that is inside the mapping method is the same object instance as in the caller).

```
void mapDTO(Arraylist<Books> booksDTOList, List<Object[]> modelList){
    Books books = null;
    for (Object[] model : modelList){
        books = new Books((String)model[0], (String)model[1]);
        booksDTOList.add(books);
    }
}
```

To answer your first question, adding objects to a List (ArrayList or otherwise) will not overwrite already existing elements in the list.

**Edit** I updated all examples with camelCase method and object names (and corrected some syntax errors).

One more change you could do (based on the information available) is to change the modelList to contain String arrays:

```
void mapDTO(Arraylist<Books> booksDTOList, List<String[]> modelList){
    Books books = null;
    for (String[] model : modelList){
        books = new Books(model[0], model[1]);
        booksDTOList.add(books);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `List` instead of `ArrayList` is generally seen as best practice in Java.
However, what's not best practice in Java is to use all lower case method names. The Java way is camelCase, in case of non-class names with a starting lower case letter